# How to create list of routes

Tags: reactjs

I want it to show the dashboard and the main page. I do it like this and I get white page:

```
               

const  MasterLayout = () => {
              <main>
                    <Routes>
                       {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                                return (
                                 route.component && (
                                 <Route
                                 key={idx}
                                 path={route.path}
                                 exact={route.exact}
                                 name={route.name}
                                 render={(props) => (
                                <route.component {...props} />
                                    )}
                                />
                            )
                        )
                    })}
                    <Navigate from="/admin" to="/admin/dashboard" />
                    </Routes>
                 </main>
```

App.js

```
 <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Routes>

        
        <Route path="/admin" name="Admin" render={(props)=> <MasterLayout {...props} /> } />
      


      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </div>
```

route.js

```
const routes = [
    
    { path: '/admin', exact: true, name: 'Admin'},
    { path: '/admin/dashboard', exact: true, name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
    { path: '/admin/profile', exact: true, name: 'Profile',  component: Profile },

];
```

Comment: A blank page usually indicates an error. What's in the browser console?

Comment: history.ts:487 No routes matched location "/admin/dashboard"

Comment: Look at basic example here
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_router.asp

Comment: Put that information in your question, please. It doesn't belong down here.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is probably to nest your route.

I've recently followed the official docs of `react-router-dom` and ended up with something like this:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Authentication />,
      },
      {
        path: '/components',
        element: <Components />,
      },
      {
        path: 'practice',
        element: <Practice />,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':collectionId',
            children: [
              {
                path: ':itemId',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
])

export const Pages = (): JSX.Element => <RouterProvider router={router} />
```

See [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#children) (currently being updated it seems).